# OneLogin SCIM provisioning for Groups

Tags: provisioning, onelogin, scim, scim2

I am building OneLogin SCIM Provisioner with SAML (Core Schema) app. I've created two controllers - Users and Groups. UsersController logic works perfectly - I can provision users and do all CRUD operations. But I am having issues with provisioning groups:

Based on the OneLogin articles ([Get Groups](https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/implement-scim-api#getgroups) and [Provision Users into Groups](https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/create-app#provgroups)) i get the initial GET hit that is trying to retrieve groups (when I refresh entitlements in OneLogin) but nothing comes accross on the OneLogin side. I've gone so far to return exact copy of the example response given in the article. Activity Event Log in OneLogin is showing that Refresh Entitlement operation has started and finished but the result of the operation is nowhere to be seen.

Has anybody experienced similar issue?

Every help and suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: have you asked them about this?

Answer (score 1):

Awesome that you're doing SCIM

In Onelogin groups and group memberships are expressed as "Entitlements" which is a fancy term for "things that can be set through rules in OneLogin"

So you need to go into your application and turn on provisioning for the Groups parameter.

Once you've refreshed entitlements (and your application has told OneLogin what groups you have) you should then be able to go into the "Rules" configuration in your OneLogin application and define rules to assign users to the various groups in your app.

Hope that helps.

Also if this is a commercial application (not something in-house) please contact scim-support@onelogin.com if you want something official and pre-configured in the OneLogin app catalog.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your suggestion. How do I turn on provisioning for the Groups parameter? Is it just ticking the "Include in User Provisioning" option in Apps > MyApp > Parameters >Groups( [screenshot](https://imgur.com/SiaAQ9X) ) or is there more to it? I've done previous step but it does not seem to affect the outcome of refreshed entitlements.

Comment: That's it. More details can be found in the docs here: https://developers.onelogin.com/scim/create-app

If it's still not working, I suspect the oneLogin parser is barfing on something you're returning from the group endpoint. It's also important to use the SCIM 2.0 connector from our catalog if you're doing SCIM 2.0 groups since the format did change between version of the spec.

Comment: @JohnOffenhartz, we are working on the same task and I realized some inconsistency in the behaviour of Groups provisioning. Sometimes post request is not send. I'm not sure, I'm able to put my finger on why and when, but happens pretty much. Users that belong to role would be provisioned, but group post request would not be send.